# What does Islam say about offering Namaz in public places?

Tags: salat, sharia

I have seen many times that Muslims often pray in public places. A couple of times I come across various posts on social media where Muslims are called out for occupying public places to offer prayer.

What does Islam say about this? What are the rulings on this?